# Find out which MSI packages are installed given a list of MSI packages with powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-installer

Here is my problem:
I'm managing a set of windows machines and need to install a set of software on those machines. For this I've shared a folder on server which will host all the software packages.

Now I keep updating this remote directory with new software packages and ask end machines to install these software. This is tedious and I need to automate this. So I need to have a script which will compare software packages in the remote directory with what packages are installed on local machine, and if new packages are found - install them.

I've already looked at GPO's in policy management and it is not applicable as it requires system reboot or user log on/off.

I know about get-wmiobject but am stuck at how to get name that will represent MSI package after installation, as name of MSI file is not same as that appears in result to get-wmiobject. And after that compare these two lists.

Comment: You should really be looking at tools like SCCM.  SCCM has inventory capabilities that will tell you whats installed across your organization.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but if you search for using Powershell with the Windows Installer object you might get somewhere because you're more directly using MSI rather than going through WMI to get to MSI.

Comment: Yes.. Heath has a cmdlet https://psmsi.codeplex.com/   Win32_Products is a dog and has all kinds of nasty side effects.

Comment: bet you're happy about yesterday's win10 package management announcement